# When to extend interfaces or use multiple interfaces or extend classes with interfaces

Tags: php, oop, interface

After reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php, I am uncertain when I should extend interfaces or use multiple interfaces or extend classes with interfaces.  What criteria does one use to determine which approach to take?

```
<?php
interface Interface_A
{
    public function aaa();
}

interface Interface_B
{
    public function bbb();
}

interface Interface_C extends Interface_A
{
    public function bbb();
}

class Class_A implements Interface_A, Interface_B
{
    public function aaa(){}
    public function bbb(){}
}

class Class_B implements Interface_C
{
    public function aaa(){}
    public function bbb(){}
}

class Class_C implements Interface_A
{
    public function aaa(){}
}

class Class_D extends Class_C implements Interface_B
{
    //public function aaa(){}  //Use parent
    public function bbb(){}
}
```

Comment: There is no single criteria. You need to do your research on existing patterns, and choose one or come up with your own designs.

Comment: @yivi  Thanks for your comment.  While I see reasons why extending a class with an existing interface may be beneficial or not over other solutions, I see no difference between extending an interface versus using multiple interfaces.  Have you come across any tutorials which describes the strategy to use one approach over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one good approach, I think, is to follow [*Composition over inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and [*Interface segregation principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) by default. This automatically will **rule out** **"extend interfaces"** and **"extend classes with interfaces"** for most cases. For the remaining cases, as always, it depends.

Interfaces are contracts, so when a class implements interfaces it shows other classes that it has appropriate methods. This provides the base for [*Liskov substitution principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

From your examples:

1. If some of your classes rely on `aaa()` method and some of your classes rely on both `aaa()` and `bbb()` methods, and none rely on `bbb()` alone, then, you, in fact, can extend `Interface_A` and thus add the method to it.
2. If all previous keeps but some of the classes also rely on `bbb()` alone, then it is better to have `Interface_A` and `Interface_B`. And if you want to enforce both those methods with one interface you can create combined one:

   interface Interface_C extends Interface_A, Interface_B
   {

   }
3. This is my subjective opinion but extending classes and also implementing the interface is a bit complex from the understanding point of view and not really useful (or I'd rather say not really practical). In general, you implement an interface, so that you can type hint it. If you type hint `Interface_B` and your `Class_D` implements it, then you should not care if this class implements any other interfaces. This means, that you can have `Class_C` as a dependency for `Class_D`, and simply can avoid using inheritance at all.